# how to create a helper that is going to render a partial view with a model?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'll give a very simple example:

at the moment I have to write like this:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("hello", new HelloInput { Name = "Jimmy" } ); %>
```

I would like to be able to like this:

```
<%=Html.Hello("Jimmy") %>
```

So I would like to know how create this helper:

```
public static string Hello(this HtmlHelper helper, string name)
{
    return the result of rendering partial view "hello" with HelloInput{ Name = name };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial is the <%= version of RenderPartial:

```
public static string Hello(this HtmlHelper helper, string name)
{
    return helper.Partial("hello", new HelloInput { Name = name } );
}
```

Comment: You may replace `new HelloInput { Name = "Jimmy" }` by `new HelloInput { Name = name }` otherwise all people are named Jimmy ;)